# Problems with toggle the display of a div in a nested svelte #each-block

Tags: javascript, svelte

I want to expand only the corresponding block by clicking on the heading. At the moment they all work at once when I click on a heading.

How do I proceed in svelte?

I tried to use the header in the data as ID. But that didn't work.

REPL: https://svelte.dev/repl/8495aab06879495ab379949778dd29f4?version=3.9.1

```
<script>
  let angebote = {
    success: true,
    liste1: [
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Abitur",
        Beschreibung:
          "Leistungskurs Deutsch, Englisch, Franz\u00f6sisch\nLeistungskurs Geschichte, Sozialwissenschaften, P\u00e4dagogik, Erdkunde\nLeistungskurs Mathematik, Biologie, Physik, Chemie",
        Firma: "Euregio-Gymnasium Gymnasium der Stadt Bocholt",
        Standnummer: "54",
        Bereich: "Obergeschoss",
        Bereichskuerzel: "OG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#EC661C",
        tags:
          "Berufsvorbereitung,weiterf\u00fchrende Schule,Vorbereitung aufs Studium"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Abitur",
        Beschreibung:
          "Leistungskurs Deutsch, Englisch, Franz\u00f6sisch\nLeistungskurs Geschichte, Sozialwissenschaften, P\u00e4dagogik, Erdkunde\nLeistungskurs Mathematik, Biologie, Physik, Chemie",
        Firma: "Gesamtschule der Stadt Bocholt mit gymnasialer Oberstufe",
        Standnummer: "52",
        Bereich: "Obergeschoss",
        Bereichskuerzel: "OG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#EC661C",
        tags:
          "Berufsvorbereitung,weiterf\u00fchrende Schule,Vorbereitung aufs Studium"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Allgemeine Hochschulreife",
        Beschreibung: "-",
        Firma: "Weiterbildungskolleg Westm\u00fcnsterland",
        Standnummer: "53",
        Bereich: "Obergeschoss",
        Bereichskuerzel: "OG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#EC661C",
        tags:
          "Vorbereitung auf Beruf,weiterf\u00fchrende Schule,Vorbereitung aufs Studium"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Altenpflegehelfer (m/w/d)",
        Beschreibung:
          "Altenpflegehelfer unterst\u00fctzen Altenpfleger bei der Betreuung, Versorgung und Pflege \u00e4lterer Menschen.",
        Firma: "Azurit Gruppe",
        Standnummer: "46",
        Bereich: "Au\u00dfenbereich",
        Bereichskuerzel: "AU",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#cc3f8b",
        tags: "Pflege,Sozial,Menschen,Senioren,F\u00fcrsorge,Medizin"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Altenpflegehelfer (m/w/d)",
        Beschreibung:
          "Altenpflegehelfer unterst\u00fctzen Altenpfleger bei der Betreuung, Versorgung und Pflege \u00e4lterer Menschen.",
        Firma: "DRK Altenpflege Bocholt",
        Standnummer: "70",
        Bereich: "Obergeschoss",
        Bereichskuerzel: "OG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#EC661C",
        tags: "Pflege,Sozial,Menschen,Senioren,F\u00fcrsorge,Medizin"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Altenpflegehelfer (m/w/d)",
        Beschreibung:
          "Altenpflegehelfer unterst\u00fctzen Altenpfleger bei der Betreuung, Versorgung und Pflege \u00e4lterer Menschen.",
        Firma: "Caritas Bildungszentrum",
        Standnummer: "70",
        Bereich: "Obergeschoss",
        Bereichskuerzel: "OG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#EC661C",
        tags: "Pflege,Sozial,Menschen,Senioren,F\u00fcrsorge,Medizin"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Altenpflegehelfer (m/w/d)",
        Beschreibung:
          "Altenpflegehelfer unterst\u00fctzen Altenpfleger bei der Betreuung, Versorgung und Pflege \u00e4lterer Menschen.",
        Firma: "Guter Hirte",
        Standnummer: "70",
        Bereich: "Obergeschoss",
        Bereichskuerzel: "OG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#EC661C",
        tags: "Pflege,Sozial,Menschen,Senioren,F\u00fcrsorge,Medizin"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Altenpflegehelfer (m/w/d)",
        Beschreibung:
          "Altenpflegehelfer unterst\u00fctzen Altenpfleger bei der Betreuung, Versorgung und Pflege \u00e4lterer Menschen.",
        Firma: "Jeanette Wolff Seniorenzentrum",
        Standnummer: "70",
        Bereich: "Obergeschoss",
        Bereichskuerzel: "OG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#EC661C",
        tags: "Pflege,Sozial,Menschen,Senioren,F\u00fcrsorge,Medizin"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Altenpflegehelfer (m/w/d)",
        Beschreibung:
          "Altenpflegehelfer unterst\u00fctzen Altenpfleger bei der Betreuung, Versorgung und Pflege \u00e4lterer Menschen.",
        Firma: "Lebenshilfe Unterer Niederrhein",
        Standnummer: "75",
        Bereich: "Tiefgarage",
        Bereichskuerzel: "TG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#74AF9B",
        tags: "Pflege,Sozial,Menschen,Senioren,F\u00fcrsorge,Medizin"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Altenpflegehelfer (m/w/d)",
        Beschreibung:
          "Altenpflegehelfer unterst\u00fctzen Altenpfleger bei der Betreuung, Versorgung und Pflege \u00e4lterer Menschen.",
        Firma: "Caritasverband Dekanat Bocholt",
        Standnummer: "91",
        Bereich: "Tiefgarage",
        Bereichskuerzel: "TG",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#74AF9B",
        tags: "Pflege,Sozial,Menschen,Senioren,F\u00fcrsorge,Medizin"
      },
      {
        Ausbildungsberufe: "Altenpfleger (m/w/d)",
        Beschreibung:
          "Altenpfleger pflegen und betreuen \u00e4ltere Menschen, die den Alltag nicht mehr allein bew\u00e4ltigen k\u00f6nnen. Durch Freizeitaktivit\u00e4ten, Gespr\u00e4che und einf\u00fchlsame F\u00fcrsorge unterst\u00fctzen sie alte Menschen, so gut es geht am t\u00e4glichen Leben teilzuhaben.",
        Firma: "Azurit Gruppe",
        Standnummer: "46",
        Bereich: "Au\u00dfenbereich",
        Bereichskuerzel: "AU",
        Bereichsfarbe: "#cc3f8b",
        tags: "Pflege,Sozial,Menschen,Senioren,F\u00fcrsorge,Medizin"
      }
    ],
    totalRecordCount: 369,
    version: "16.0.1"
  };

  Array.prototype.groupBy = function(prop) {
    return this.reduce(function(groups, item) {
      const val = item[prop];
      groups[val] = groups[val] || [];
      groups[val].push(item);
      return groups;
    }, {});
  };

  let abfrage = [];
  let items = angebote.liste1.groupBy("Ausbildungsberufe");
  let unsichtbar = true;

</script>

<style>
    .info {display:none;}
</style>

{#each Object.keys(items) as item, i (item)}
  <h4 on:click={()=>unsichtbar=!unsichtbar}>
        {i + 1}) {item}
    </h4>
    <div class:info={unsichtbar}>
        {#each items[item] as angebot}
            {angebot.Firma} / {angebot.Bereich} / {angebot.Standnummer}
            <br />
        {:else}
            Keine Firmen vorhanden.
        {/each}
    </div>
 <hr />
{:else}
    keine Angebote vorhanden
{/each}
```

I expect  to display one single block and not all these blocks.

Comment: at the moment you have a single variable `unsichtbar` for all these blocks. if you want to toggle only a single block, then you need to distinct between `unsichtbar` for item 1 and `unsichtbar` for item 1234. You could make `unsichbar` an Array or you could extract the actual markup for an entry into a seperate component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you cannot use a single variable as a flag for multiple elements. It is only natural for all elements to open if you do use a single flag. Instead, you can make use of an array.

```
let unsichtbar = [];
```

Then in your template, you need to change the `on:click` to `{()=>unsichtbar[i]=!unsichtbar[i]}`

Rather than using a class to show/hide your div using css, you can use an if block. The template will now look like this

```
{#each Object.keys(items) as item, i (item)}
    <h4 on:click={() => unsichtbar[i]=!unsichtbar[i]}>
        {i + 1}) {item}
    </h4>
    {#if unsichtbar[i]}
        <div>
            {#each items[item] as angebot}
                {angebot.Firma} / {angebot.Bereich} / {angebot.Standnummer}
                <br />
            {:else}
                Keine Firmen vorhanden.
            {/each}
        </div>
    {/if}
    <hr />
{:else}
    keine Angebote vorhanden
{/each}
```

Here is a working [example](https://svelte.dev/repl/75c3ee12e81344c59c38f2c721d96681?version=3.9.1).

Comment: Thank you for that. i hoped svelte has a magic trick for that problem.

Comment: You're welcome  I don't think it would make sense for them to make a fix for this. At least not in this way. Encapsulating the scope of `unsichtbar` for every `each` block would cause other issues. This method at least goes along with the understanding of basic Javascript.